# Getting error: no matching version `^2.0.0` found for package `codec`?

Tags: substrate

**Question**

I'm new to Substrate and going through **Add a Pallet to Your Runtime**. At first, running the command `cargo check -p node-template-runtime` gave me error

```
error: failed to parse manifest at `/Users/bashar/work/substrate/start/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  feature `rename-dependency` is required

consider adding `cargo-features = ["rename-dependency"]` to the manifest
```

I added it and then I started getting this error:

```
error: no matching version `^2.0.0` found for package `codec`                                                                                                                                                  
location searched: registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
versions found: 0.0.0
required by package `frame-benchmarking-cli v3.0.0`
    ... which is depended on by `node-template v3.0.0 (/Users/bashar/work/substrate/start/substrate-node-template/node)`
```

I tried modifying the codec version to `2.0.1` with no luck. My setup

```
rustup 1.23.1
rustc 1.50.0
cargo 1.30.0
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I went back to the [Create Your First Substrate Chain](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup), which this tutorial is built on, started from scratch, which the Pallet tutorial is based on. And this time, after cloning the repository for first tutorial, `cargo build --release` failed with the same error  `feature` rename-dependency `is required`.

This built fine the first time before I moved to the second tutorial. Which makes me think maybe a recent Mac update ruined something? I even tried uninstalling Rust and re-installing it, then installing a new template. Same thing

Comment: The first error looks like you copied something wrong or forgot to follow  some steps where you are supposed to rename something. Can you share more specific code which is failing?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi ok interesting. I just went back to Your First Substrate Chain tutorial to redo the whole thing, I downloaded the code and now cargo build --release gives the same error!

Comment: can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ? I also see you are using substrate 2.0.0 dependencies, are you mixing major versions? The tuto is v3, so you need to be using all the same major versions to expect things to work. I would suggest trying with a fresh 3.0.0 template.

Comment: When you search "rename-dependency" in your project, what shows up?

Comment: @NukeManDan Thanks for your input. I have already done uninstall and reinstall to Rust, and started with fresh template 3.0.0. The first tutorial https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup fails with first build command. I tried to clarify again in my post update. Looking now to see any changes on my device that might have happened.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi nothing found. Right now I'm testing on First tutorial without making any changes myself https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup

Comment: Never mind. It was my stupid mistake when I added cargo to the path wrongly